# Get service manager instance inside event listner zend framework2

Tags: php, events, zend-framework2

I have a mapper class "User" with findAll() function.

```
public function findAll()
 {        
  /**
  * Fetch records from table 'User'

  *@author Administrator
  */

    $this->getEventManager()->trigger('find', $this, array('entity' => $entity));
    return $entity;

}
```

Here I am triggering a event which is listening by the user's module class

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{

    $eventManager       = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

    $sm = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();


    $sharedEventManager->attach('ZfcUser\Mapper\User', 'find', function($e) {

         /*
          Access log create object
         */

    }, 100);

}
```

Really I want this to add log record in to database, I have prepared a service to return a object that capable of write this record to DB.

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
               'Dblogger' => function($sm) {

                $logger = $sm->get('logger');
                $plugin = new Controller\Plugin\Log;
                $plugin->setLogger($logger);
                return $plugin;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

With using this service its all I have to do is call this method

```
$sm = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$logger = $sm->get('Dblogger');
$logger->Debug('View the user list');
```

But my problem is, there is no anyway to call this service inside this closure function

```
 $sharedEventManager->attach('ZfcUser\Mapper\User', 'find', function($e) {

         /*
          Access log create object
         */

    }, 100);
```

Please help me to comeup with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a cleaner solution, but i simply `use` it:

```
$sEM->attach('Namespace', 'eventName', function(Event $e) use ($serviceManager) {
    $serviceManager->get('fooBar');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{

    $eventManager       = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

    $sm = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();


    $sharedEventManager->attach('ZfcUser\Mapper\User', 'find', function($e) use ($sm) {

         /*
          Access log create object
         */
         $sm->....

    }, 100);

}
```